# How to avoide a "potential resource leak" warning when using explicit constructor invocation?

Tags: java, constructor, resource-leak

In my old code, I often used the following constructor idiom for convenience:

```
MyClass( InputStream input ) {
  // do actual stuff
}
MyClass( String filename ) {
  this( new FileInputStream(filename) )
}
```

This leads to Eclipse warning me of a **"Potential resource leak: '<unassigned Closeable value>' may not be closed"** in the explicit constructor invocation.

Usually, I would use a try-with block for the auto-closable FileInputStream, but this is not possible here since the invocation must always be the first statement in a constructor. That is, the following **does not compile**:

```
MyClass( InputStream input ) {
  // do actual stuff
}
MyClass( String filename ) {
  try( FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename) ) {
    this( fis );
  }
}
```

So, what would be the correct (and elegant?) way to use this idiom without the risk of a potential resource leak? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you could wrap the constructor call in a `try-with-resources`, does it really make sense? The constructor is most likely storing the `InputStream` in some internal state, so closing it in the constructor makes it invalid when subsequently used in other methods of the class.

A better solution is to make `MyClass` implement `AutoCloseable` and close the input stream in the `close()` method, hence giving users of your class control over how to close the input stream that is passed to the `MyClass` instance.